# Adding build-time warnings to visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, warnings, switch-statement

Unsure if this is the right forum, but here we are.  Here's the question, sans background, for the tl;dr crowd:

> Is there a way to make Visual Studio give a build-time warning when I make a switch block without a default case?

The reason for this is that I use enumerations pretty heavily, and typically the default value  should never happen.  When it does, it's because I added another case to the enum, and I'd prefer that to throw a NotImplementedException (while I'm testing!) in case I forget to update something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you really want a compiler warning. A missing default case is totally valid, so the compiler is the least place where such a feature belongs.

That said, there are tools like FxCop doing code analysis. FxCop can be integrated to the build process. The violations will show up as warnings in the build result window.

See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/codeanalysis/archive/2007/02/24/faq-how-do-i-run-fxcop-during-a-post-build-event.aspx how to integrate FxCop

Comment: You're right; I don't want a compiler warning (since not doing it is certainly valid code), but I do want a compile-time warning.  I've edited the main post to say "build-time" over "compile-time" to make this more clear (and more correct, I guess).  Anyway, checking out FxCop now.